# If a subspace is dense in a reflexive Banach space, then "it" is dense in the dual?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

It is well-known that if a Banach space $X$ is reflexive and separable, then its dual $X'$ is separable. My question is more concrete, but for clarity, I am going to state a few questions going from most general to most concrete:

1. Suppose it is known that the Banach space $X$ is reflexive, and a subspace $Z$ of $X$ is dense in $X$. Let $T:Z\rightarrow X'$ be an arbitrary injective embedding. Does it follow that $T(Z)$ is dense in $X'$? **Answer: No** (see Nate's comment).
2. Suppose $X$ is a Hilbert space, and $Z$ is a subspace of $X$ which is dense in $X$. Do not identify $X$ with its dual. Furthermore, suppose that there exists a map $T:X\rightarrow X'$ such that the elements of $T(Z)$ coincide with a subset of those of $Z$. Does it follow that $T(Z)$ is dense in $X'$?
3. Suppose $X$ is a Hilbert space whose elements are measurable functions and such that the elements of a subspace $Z$ of $X$ coincide with those of $C_c^{\infty}$, and $Z$ is dense in $X$. Do not identify $X$ with its dual. Furthermore, suppose that the elements of a subspace $Z'$ of $X'$ coincide with those of $C_c^{\infty}$. Does it follow that $Z'$ is dense in $X'$?

Note that in the concrete case of question 3 with $X=H^1=W^{1,2}(\mathbb R^n)$, the question has been resolved with answer "yes", by reuns below.

I am most interested in the answer to question 3, in the general setting.

Comment: For the general case, how is $C_c^\infty$ identified with a subspace of $X'$?

Comment: Ok...assume that $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb R^n)$ is a subspace of $X'$ in the general case. Honestly, a resolution for the Hilbert space case would be interesting enough for me.

Comment: I think that the answer depends essentially on *how* $C_c^\infty$ is seen as a subspace of $X'$. In the general case, the assumption "$C_c^{\infty}$ is a subspace of $X'$" means only that an injective linear map $T:C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb R^n)\to X'$ is given (under the usual identification in the Hilbert space case, $T$ is an isometry). You want to know whether $T(C_c^\infty)$ is dense in $X'$. I think that only linearity and injectivity are not enough to prove it (in the Hilbert space case under the usual identification, $T$ is also defined on the entire space, bijective and continuous).

Comment: As $X$ is arbitrary and $C_c^\infty$ is seen as subspace of $X'$ in no specific way, I cannot see what is special about $C_c^\infty$. So, I think your question can be written as: given a reflexive space $X$, a dense subspace $Z\subset X$ and an injective linear map $T:Z\to X'$, is it true that $T(Z)$ is dense in $X'$? What about in addition $X$ is Hilbert?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Pedro. You are right that the question can be written in a more general way; but even a proof in a concrete case would be useful for me. For instance a proof for the case $X=W^{1,2}(\mathbb R^n)$, $Z=C_c^{\infty}$ would be very enlightening to me, although ideally I am indeed looking for a more general result.

Comment: $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in the distributions which is the weak dual of $D(\mathbb{R})$. So $C^\infty_c$ is dense in $(W^{1,2})'$ for the **weak** topology. I think your question is if the weak dual of $X$ is dense in the strong dual

Comment: @Pedro and reuns, please check my latest edit.

Comment: @Lentes I'd say "The proof is over as soon as one has $\psi(Z)\subseteq\overline{T(Z)}$, where $T$ is the particular [embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding) from $X$ to $X'$ under consideration". In the case where we identify the space with its dual, we have $T=\psi$ and we are done. It seems you interested in the case in which the embedding $T$ is completly arbitrary, right?

Comment: @Pedro , well I am primarily interested in spaces where elements are measurable functions, so the elements of $T(Z)$ should really coincide with those of $Z$ in the sense of measurable functions. But, it is true that I do not want $T=\psi$.

Take the concrete case of $X=W^{1,2}(\mathbb R^n)$. Then
$$ X\subsetneq L^2(\mathbb R^n)\subsetneq X',$$ and it is clear that the smooth compactly supported functions form subspaces in all three spaces in the above chain.

Comment: @Pedro I have edited my question to clarify it better; thanks for your help with that. Do you think the question is stated clearly now?

Comment: The most usual setting for this sort of thing is a *Gelfand triple*; you have a reflexive Banach space $X$ and a Hilbert space $H$ with a continuous injection $i : X \to H$ whose image is dense.  Then you can show the adjoint $i' : H \to X'$ is also a continous injection whose image is dense.  Thus if $E$ is dense in $X$, then $i'(i(E))$ is dense in $X'$.

Comment: 1 is certainly false: let $X = X' = Z = \ell^2$ and take $T$ to be right shift.

Comment: @NateEldredge thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $W^{1,2}$  you can try something like this :

As $C^\infty_c$ is dense in the distributions, it is more or less obvious $C^\infty_c$ is dense in the weak dual of $H^1 = W^{1,2}$  the Hilbert space with norm $\|f\|_{H^1}^2 = \|f\|_{L^2}^2+\|f'\|_{L^2}^2$.

So the question is if it is also dense in the strong dual.

With the Fourier transform $$\|f\|_{H^1}^2 = \int_{-\infty }^\infty |\widehat{f}(\xi)|^2d\xi +\int_{-\infty }^\infty |\widehat{f}(\xi)|^24 \pi^2 \xi^2 d\xi = \|\widehat{f} \sqrt{1+4 \pi \xi^2}\|^2_{L^2}$$
Thus its strong dual is $H^{-1}$ the Hilbert space with norm $\|g\|_{H^{-1}}^2 = \|\frac{\textstyle\widehat{g} }{\sqrt{1+4 \pi \xi^2}}\|^2_{L^2}$. 
It is not hard to check the Schwartz space is dense on the Fourier side for the $\|\frac{. }{\sqrt{1+4 \pi \xi^2}}\|^2_{L^2}$ norm, and as the Schwartz space is its own Fourier transform, the Schwartz space is dense in $H^{-1}$, and so is $C^\infty_c$.

Comment: Thanks for this, reuns; this is very helpful. Yes, I do mean denseness in the dual space in the strong topology. The abstract question, even in the Hilbert space setting, is still open, so I'll leave the question open for now.

Comment: reuns and @Lentes My conclusion is that $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ is **not** dense in ($W^{1,2}(\mathbb R^n))'$ (see my post). What is the mistake?

Comment: @Pedro Are you saying if $T$ is continuous then $T(X)$ is a closed/complete subspace of $X'$ ? For $u \in l^2$ define $\|u\|_B^2 = \sum_n |u_n|^2 e^{-n^2}$ then $l^2$ is dense in $B$ and the identity $\iota : l^2 \to B$ is continuous but $\iota(l^2) \ne B$

Comment: @reuns I was wrong about that (in fact, in general only one side of the inclusion is valid). I deleted the post. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah; there is actually a different argument to conclude that $C_c^{\infty}$ is dense in $H^{-1}$ (with the added nicety that the argument works if we replace $\mathbb R^n$ by any open set $\Omega$). The argument is this: if $f\in H^{-1}$, then by Riesz Representation there exists a unique $u\in H^1$ such that
$$
-\Delta u+u =f
$$
in the weak sense. The above actually defines an invertible, isometric mapping $\psi: H^1\rightarrow H^{-1}$. It is clear that $\psi(C_c^{\infty})\subseteq C_c^{\infty}$, and since $\psi(C_c^{\infty})$ is dense in $H^{-1}$, so too must be $C_c^{\infty}$.

Comment: @Lentes Sorry it is unclear to me. How do you find the structure of $H^{-1}$ starting from $g \in H^1 \Leftrightarrow g,g' \in L^2$ ?

Comment: @reuns In the PDE book of Evans, see section 5.9.1 in page 299 (the second edition). It gives the precise structure of $H^{-1}$.